# Multiple Dynamic Selects in Angular with multiple lines

Tags: arrays, angular, forms

Hoping someone can help!

I am working on a test app which you need to enter various values based on a time, like a time sheet almost.

The first 2 select fields are retrieved via an API in a single call with projects and tasks, which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "project": "First Project",
        "code": "123",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "code": "1",
                "name": "Some Task"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "project": "Project 6",
        "code": "456",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "code": "99",
                "name": "A task 1"
            },
            {
                "code": "100",
                "name": "A Task 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "project": "Project 2",
        "code": "5678",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "code": "1",
                "name": "Task 1"
            },
            {
                "code": "2",
                "name": "Task 2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have successfully retrieved the data from the API and populated the first select box like this:

```
<th scope="row" class="col-2">
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Select a project">
    <option disabled>[SELECT PROJECT]</option>
    <option [value]="timecode.code" [selected]="timecode.code == entry.project" *ngFor="let timecode of timecodes">({{ timecode.code }}) {{ timecode.project }}</option>
</select>
```

This works as expected, my issue is with populating hte second  select with the calues based on the first select in the following ways:

1. on load - The select shoudl be populated and selected with the correct value
2. on change of the select or on a new line populate with the data based on the first.
   The payload for the select I am not too worried about it is just the dynamically selecting from the array based upon the project.

I have tried creating a function and passing the project code in:

```
getTasksForProject(projectCode: string): any {
    let project = this.timecodes.filter(proj => proj.code == projectCode);
    console.log(project)
    return project.tasks;
}

<td scope="row" class="col-2">
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Select a task" [disabled]="!entry.project">
    <option disabled>[SELECT TASK]</option>
    <option [value]="task.code" *ngFor="let task of getTasksForProject(entry.project)">({{ task.code }}) {{ task.code }}</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

But this returnd nothing?

Also this will have multiple entry lines which will be dynamically added.

Any advice much appreciated!

Regards

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue I'm seeing here is that in your for loop you are passing

**entry.project**

try **entry.code** instead. since in your **getTasksForProject** method you use code for the filtering.

```
    <option [value]="task.code" *ngFor="let task of getTasksForProject(entry.code)">({{ task.code }}) {{ task.code }}</option>
```